# Activity restart on rotation Android

Tags: android, rotation, android-activity

In my Android application, when I rotate the device (slide out the keyboard) then my `Activity` is restarted (`onCreate` is called). Now, this is probably how it's supposed to be, but I do a lot of initial setting up in the `onCreate` method, so I need either:

1. Put all the initial setting up in another function so it's not all lost on device rotation or
2. Make it so `onCreate` is not called again and the layout just adjusts or
3. Limit the app to just portrait so that `onCreate` is not called.

Comment: There is a rather complete explanation on how to retain long-running asynchronous tasks during activity configuration changes in [**this blog post**](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html) too!

Comment: This is not a direct answer as others have answered already, but I invite you to have a look at [LogLifeCycle](https://github.com/stephanenicolas/loglifecycle) to understand what happens in your android apps regarding to life cycles.

Answer (score 996, accepted):

### Using the Application Class

Depending on what you're doing in your initialization you could consider creating a new class that extends `Application` and moving your initialization code into an overridden `onCreate` method within that class.

### Kotlin version

```kotlin
class MyApplicationClass: Application {
    @override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        // Put your application initialization code here
    }
}
```

### Java version

```java
public class MyApplicationClass extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        // Put your application initialization code here
    }
}
```

The `onCreate` in the application class is only called when the entire application is created, so the Activity restarts on orientation or keyboard visibility changes won't trigger it.

It's good practice to expose the instance of this class as a singleton and exposing the application variables you're initializing using getters and setters.

*NOTE: You'll need to specify the name of your new Application class in the manifest for it to be registered and used:*

```
<application
    android:name="com.you.yourapp.MyApplicationClass"
```

### Reacting to Configuration Changes

*UPDATE: This is deprecated since API 13; [see the recommended alternative](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html)*

As a further alternative, you can have your application listen for events that would cause a restart – like orientation and keyboard visibility changes – and handle them within your Activity.

Start by adding the `android:configChanges` node to your Activity's manifest node:

```
 <activity android:name=".MyActivity"
      android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
      android:label="@string/app_name">
```

Or for [Android 3.2 (API level 13) and newer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9550231/2291):

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
      android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
      android:label="@string/app_name">
```

Then within the Activity override the `onConfigurationChanged` method and call `setContentView` to force the GUI layout to be re-done in the new orientation.

### Kotlin version

```kotlin
@override fun onConfigurationChanged(newConfig: Configuration) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig)
    setContentView(R.layout.myLayout)
}
```

### Java version

```kotlin
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    setContentView(R.layout.myLayout);
}
```

Comment: I dont think the second approach works. I tried it; one Activity with a EditText. I wrote some text there, change orientation and the text was gone/reset.

Comment: Here's hoping we see an onRotate() method in the future. Having to even worry about things like this is—frankly—frustrating.

Comment: Don't forget the `keyboardHidden` in `android:configChanges`. I did, and it caused the activity to be destroyed and recreated anyway.

Comment: Note that [the Android Dev Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config) cautions against using this:  **Note: Using (`android:configChanges`) should be avoided and used only as a last-resort. Please read Handling Runtime Changes for more information about how to properly handle a restart due to a configuration change.**  In lieu, to persist data across rotation events, they seem to prefer using the `onSaveInstanceState Bundle`; or as @Jon-O [mentions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7509094/260559), `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance`.

Comment: I think you should add [this update on 3.2](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9550231/503900) to your answer, it's quite important (just faced that problem) and it might get overlooked.

Comment: using `android:configChanges` saves me a ton of work, so I hate it when Google tells me only to use it as a last resort without explaining *why*. Give me a reason not to save a ton of work. Please.

Comment: Google says not to use `android:configChanges` because:
_Handling the configuration change yourself can make it much more difficult to use alternative resources, because the system does not automatically apply them for you_ [source](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange)
It seems reasonable to prevent portrait/landscape with this, since you're saying you don't want it handled at all.

Caveat: Am android n00b.

Comment: In the last code, don't use setContentView. It will work properly.

Comment: @KellySutton 12 years later, and insted of that onRotate() method, a whole new design pattern was invented. Oh well

Answer (score 192):

Update for Android 3.2 and higher:

> **Caution**: Beginning with Android 3.2 (API level 13), **the "screen size" also changes** when the device switches between portrait and landscape orientation. Thus, if you want to prevent runtime restarts due to orientation change when developing for API level 13 or higher (as declared by the minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion attributes), you must include the `"screenSize"` value in addition to the `"orientation"` value. That is, you must declare `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"`. However, if your application targets API level 12 or lower, then your activity always handles this configuration change itself (this configuration change does not restart your activity, even when running on an Android 3.2 or higher device).

From http://web.archive.org/web/20120805085007/http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

Comment: Thanks for that clarification, since a comment above on this almost sent me off to look into it.  I'm presently targeting API 8 and my code does not have screenSize on configChanges and can confirm that it works fine (without re-orienting) on the device I have that is running ICS.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, I had only android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" set, and orientation switching was recreating my Activity, and for the life of me I couldn't figure out why!

Comment: Adding android:configChanges **should only be used as a last resort**. Consider using `Fragments` and `setRetainInstance` instead.

Comment: The key point is `screenSize` for Android 3.2 and higher, that solved my problem, Thank you!

Answer (score 137):

Instead of trying to stop the `onCreate()` from being fired altogether, maybe try checking the `Bundle` `savedInstanceState` being passed into the event to see if it is null or not.

For instance, if I have some logic that should be run when the `Activity` is truly created, not on every orientation change, I only run that logic in the `onCreate()` only if the `savedInstanceState` is null.

Otherwise, I still want the layout to redraw properly for the orientation.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game_list);

        if(savedInstanceState == null){
            setupCloudMessaging();
        }
}
```

not sure if this is the ultimate answer, but it works for me.

Comment: and where are u actually saving state?

Comment: this seems to work for me and it seems by far the simplest method. i notice you only got 4 ups for this (5 including mine) vs. 373 for the idea about subclassing Application, which to me seems far more complicated. is there any downside this this method?

Comment: This solution worked GREAT for me. i was able to `Intent serverintent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MessageListener.class);` and `startService(serverintent);` to create a `serverSocket = new ServerSocket(0xcff2);` and `Socket client = serverSocket.accept();` with a `BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));` and could rotate my android and keep the client/server connection active, yet have the GUI rotate. According to the manual, savedInstanceState  gets initialized when the last activity is shut down.

Comment: I don't understand, what's the catch? This works great, and with much less complexity than any of the other solutions.

Comment: This is the correct way to do it in Android. The other ways of basically catching a rotating with configChanges and all that are bulky, complex, and unnecessary.

Answer (score 104):

what I did...

in the manifest, to the activity section, added:

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

in the code for the activity, implemented:

```
//used in onCreate() and onConfigurationChanged() to set up the UI elements
public void InitializeUI()
{
    //get views from ID's
    this.textViewHeaderMainMessage = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.TextViewHeaderMainMessage);

    //etc... hook up click listeners, whatever you need from the Views
}

//Called when the activity is first created.
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    InitializeUI();
}

//this is called when the screen rotates.
// (onCreate is no longer called when screen rotates due to manifest, see: android:configChanges)
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
{
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    InitializeUI();
}
```

Comment: to clarify: with my implementation you can now have variable initialization in onCreate() and onConfigurationChanged() will simply be called for the screen rotation. Your variables are now insulated from screen rotations   ;-) nice and ez

Comment: I did everything just as described here, but I get NullPointerException when I try to press a button after orientation change. What could be wrong?

Comment: keep in mind my answer is like 3 years old and Android keeps evolving... Simon - do you have a link to sample code? That's what people need.

Comment: When warning against android:configChanges, @SimonAndréForsberg is actually just paraphrasing the [Android docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config). [Handling Runtime Changes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html) has more detailed information on the alternatives (including sample code).

Answer (score 71):

What you describe is the default behavior.  You have to detect and handle these events yourself by adding:

```
android:configChanges
```

to your manifest and then the changes that you want to handle.  So for orientation, you would use:

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

and for the keyboard being opened or closed you would use:

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden"
```

If you want to handle both you can just separate them with the pipe command like:

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

This will trigger the onConfigurationChanged method in whatever Activity you call.  If you override the method you can pass in the new values.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @GregD I know, which is why now is a good time to update it to reflect the situation of today. Given the number of upvotes this question has, it is still being referred to from other questions on SO.

Answer (score 52):

I just discovered this lore:

For keeping the Activity alive through an orientation change, and handling it through `onConfigurationChanged`, [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange) and [the code sample above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456211/activity-restart-on-rotation-android/456918#456918) suggest this in the Manifest file:

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
      android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
      android:label="@string/app_name">
```

which has the extra benefit that it always works.

The bonus lore is that omitting the `keyboardHidden` may seem logical, but it causes failures in the emulator (for Android 2.1 at least): specifying only `orientation` will make the emulator call both `OnCreate` and `onConfigurationChanged` sometimes, and only `OnCreate` other times.

I haven't seen the failure on a device, but I have heard about the emulator failing for others.  So it's worth documenting.

Comment: Caution: Beginning with Android 3.2 (API level 13), the "screen size" also changes when the device switches between portrait and landscape orientation. Thus, if you want to prevent runtime restarts due to orientation change when developing for API level 13 or higher:
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"

Answer (score 40):

You might also consider using the Android platform's way of persisting data across orientation changes:  `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()` and `getLastNonConfigurationInstance()`.

This allows you to persist data across configuration changes, such as information you may have gotten from a server fetch or something else that's been computed in `onCreate` or since, while also allowing Android to re-layout your `Activity` using the xml file for the orientation now in use.

See [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/02/faster-screen-orientation-change.html) or [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html).

It should be noted that these methods are now deprecated (although still more flexible than handling orientation change yourself as most of the above solutions suggest) with the recommendation that everyone switch to `Fragments` and instead use `setRetainInstance(true)` on each `Fragment` you want to retain.

Comment: I really think Fragments and setRetainInstance is the best way (and recommended way by Google) to do this, +1 to you and -1 to all the others. Adding android:configChanges **should only be used as a last resort**

Answer (score 34):

The approach is useful but is incomplete when using Fragments.

Fragments usually get recreated on configuration change. If you don't wish this to happen, use

`setRetainInstance(true);` in the Fragment's constructor(s)

This will cause fragments to be retained during configuration change.

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setRetainInstance(boolean)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setRetainInstance%28boolean%29)

Comment: Agreed. With the latest Android API, it seems Fragments are the correct way to handle this. I haven't tried it yet myself, but from what I've gathered reading [this page](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html), you basically move 99% of what you used to implement in an Activity into a subclass of a Fragment, then add that Fragment to the Activity. The activity will still be destroyed and recreated on screen rotation, but you can specifically tell android _not_ to destroy the Fragment using the `setRetainInstance()` method @Abdo mentioned.

Answer (score 27):

I just simply added:

```
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file and **did not add** any `onConfigurationChanged` method in my activity.

So every time the keyboard slides out or in nothing happens! Also checkout this [article](http://www.coboltforge.com/2012/08/tech-stuff-prevent-android-app-from-restarting-after-sliding-out-the-hardware-keyboard/) about this problem.

Answer (score 21):

The `onCreate` method is still called even when you change the `orientation` of android. So moving all the heavy functionality to this method is not going to help you

Answer (score 21):

Put the code below inside your `<activity>` tag in `Manifest.xml`:

```
android:configChanges="screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
```

Answer (score 20):

It is very simple just do the following steps:

```
<activity
    android:name=".Test"
    android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
    android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
</activity>
```

This works for me :

**Note:** orientation depends on your requitement

Answer (score 19):

```
onConfigurationChanged is called when the screen rotates. 
(onCreate is no longer called when the screen rotates due to manifest, see:  
android:configChanges)
```

What part of the manifest tells it "don't call `onCreate()`"?

Also,
Google's docs say to avoid using `android:configChanges` (except as a last resort). But then the alternative methods they suggest all *DO* use `android:configChanges`.

It has been my experience that the emulator ALWAYS calls `onCreate()` upon rotation.
But the 1-2 devices that I run the same code on... do not.
(Not sure why there would be any difference.)

Answer (score 17):

Changes to be made in the Android manifest are:

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

Additions to be made inside activity are:

```
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    // Checks the orientation of the screen
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 17):

Add this line to your manifest :-

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenSize|screenLayout|uiMode"
```

and this snippet to the activity :-

```
@Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    }
```

Answer (score 16):

There are several ways to do this:

### **Save Activity State**

You can save the activity state in `onSaveInstanceState`.

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    /*Save your data to be restored here
    Example: outState.putLong("time_state", time); , time is a long variable*/
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

and then use the `bundle` to restore the state.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if(savedInstanceState!= null){
       /*When rotation occurs
        Example : time = savedInstanceState.getLong("time_state", 0); */
    } else {
      //When onCreate is called for the first time
    }
}
```

### Handle orientation changes by yourself

Another alternative is to handle the orientation changes by yourself. But this is not considered a good practice.

Add this to your manifest file.

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

for Android 3.2 and later:

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration config) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(config);
    
if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        //Handle rotation from landscape to portrait mode here
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){
        //Handle rotation from portrait to landscape mode here
    }
}
```

### Restrict rotation

You can also confine your activity to portrait or landscape mode to avoid rotation.

Add this to the activity tag in your manifest file:

```
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

Or implement this programmatically in your activity:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Even though it is not "the Android way" I have gotten very good results by handling orientation changes myself and simply repositioning the widgets within a view to take the altered orientation into account.  This is faster than any other approach, because your views do not have to be saved and restored.  It also provides a more seamless experience to the user, because the respositioned widgets are exactly the same widgets, just moved and/or resized.  Not only model state, but also view state, can be preserved in this manner.

`RelativeLayout` can sometimes be a good choice for a view that has to reorient itself from time to time.  You just provide a set of portrait layout params and a set of landscaped layout params, with different relative positioning rules on each, for each child widget.  Then, in your `onConfigurationChanged()` method, you pass the appropriate one to a `setLayoutParams()` call on each child.  If any child control itself needs to be *internally* reoriented, you just call a method on that child to perform the reorientation.  That child similarly calls methods on any of *its* child controls that need internal reorientation, and so on.

Comment: I would love to see some sample code of this, seems brilliant !

Answer (score 12):

The way I have found to do this is use the `onRestoreInstanceState` and the `onSaveInstanceState` events to save something in the `Bundle` (even if you dont need any variables saved, just put something in there so the `Bundle` isn't empty). Then, on the `onCreate` method, check to see if the `Bundle` is empty, and if it is, then do the initialization, if not, then do it.

Answer (score 10):

Every time when the screen is rotated, opened activity is finished and onCreate() is called again.

1 . You can do one thing save the state of activity when the screen is rotated so that, You can recover all old stuff when the activity's onCreate() is called again.
Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41804128/3578677.)  link

2 . If you want to prevent restarting of the activity just place the following lines in your manifest.xml file.

```
<activity android:name=".Youractivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"/>
```

Answer (score 8):

you need to use the onSavedInstanceState method to store all the values to its parameter is has which is a bundle

```
@Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState, PersistableBundle outPersistentState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState, outPersistentState);
        outPersistentState.putBoolean("key",value);
    }
```

and use

```
@Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        savedInstanceState.getBoolean("key");
    }
```

to retrieve and set the value to view objects
it will handle the screen rotations

Answer (score 7):

**Note:** I post this answer if someone in the future face the same problem as me. For me the following line wasn't enough:

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

When I rotated the screen, the method `onConfigurationChanged(Configuration new config) didn't get called.

**Solution:** I also had to add "screenSize" even if the problem had to do with the orientation. So in the AndroidManifest.xml - file, add this:

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

Then implement the method `onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)`

Answer (score 6):

In the activity section of the `manifest`, add:

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

Answer (score 6):

**Add this line in manifest :** `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"`

Answer (score 6):

People are saying that you should use

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

But the best and most professional way to handle rotation in Android is to use the Loader class. It's not a famous class(I don't know why), but it is way better than the AsyncTask. For more information, you can read the Android tutorials found in Udacity's Android courses.

Of course, as another way, you could store the values or the views with onSaveInstanceState and read them with onRestoreInstanceState. It's up to you really.

Comment: Yeah, let's add gobs of extra code to look "professional". Or how about just stick to the quick, easy, true and tried way of doing it with the configurationChanges attribute.

Answer (score 5):

One of the best components of android architecture introduced by google will fulfill all the requirements that are ViewModel.

That is designed to store and manage UI-related data in a lifecycle way plus that will allow data to survive as the screen rotates

```
class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {
```

Please refer to this: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel

Answer (score 4):

Fix the screen orientation (landscape or portrait) in `AndroidManifest.xml`

`android:screenOrientation="portrait"` or `android:screenOrientation="landscape"`

for this your `onResume()` method is not called.

Comment: how the hell fixing something is an answer? Why can our devices rotate if we lock users using it?

Answer (score 4):

Put this below code in your `Activity` in `Android Manifest`.

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

This will not restart your activity when you would change orientation.

Comment: @Mavamaarten Probably because as others have pointed, it's bad pratice and ten other answers have already covered this.

Answer (score 4):

Use `orientation` listener to perform different tasks on different orientation.

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration myConfig) 
{
    super.onConfigurationChanged(myConfig);
    int orient = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation; 
    switch(orient) 
    {
       case Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE:
          setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
                    break;
       case Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT:
          setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
                    break;
       default:
          setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

After a while of trial and error, I found a solution which fits my needs in the most situations. Here is the Code:

**Manifest configuration:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.pepperonas.myapplication">

    <application
        android:name=".App"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**MainActivity:**

```
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    private Fragment mFragment;

    private int mSelected = -1;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate  " + "");

        // null check not realy needed - but just in case...
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {

            initUi();

            // get an instance of FragmentTransaction from your Activity
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

            /*IMPORTANT: Do the INITIAL(!) transaction only once!
            * If we call this everytime the layout changes orientation,
            * we will end with a messy, half-working UI.
            * */
            mFragment = FragmentOne.newInstance(mSelected = 0);
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.frame, mFragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        Log.d(TAG, "onConfigurationChanged  " +
                   (newConfig.orientation
                    == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE
                    ? "landscape" : "portrait"));

        initUi();

        Log.i(TAG, "onConfigurationChanged - last selected: " + mSelected);
        makeFragmentTransaction(mSelected);
    }


    /**
     * Called from {@link #onCreate} and {@link #onConfigurationChanged}
     */
    private void initUi() {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate  instanceState == null / reinitializing..." + "");
        Button btnFragmentOne = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_fragment_one);
        Button btnFragmentTwo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_fragment_two);
        btnFragmentOne.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnFragmentTwo.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    /**
     * Not invoked (just for testing)...
     */
    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        Log.d(TAG, "onSaveInstanceState  " + "YOU WON'T SEE ME!!!");
    }


    /**
     * Not invoked (just for testing)...
     */
    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d(TAG, "onSaveInstanceState  " + "YOU WON'T SEE ME, AS WELL!!!");
    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.d(TAG, "onResume  " + "");
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Log.d(TAG, "onPause  " + "");
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy  " + "");
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btn_fragment_one:
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick btn_fragment_one " + "");
                makeFragmentTransaction(0);
                break;

            case R.id.btn_fragment_two:
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick btn_fragment_two " + "");
                makeFragmentTransaction(1);
                break;

            default:
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick  null - wtf?!" + "");
        }
    }


    /**
     * We replace the current Fragment with the selected one.
     * Note: It's called from {@link #onConfigurationChanged} as well.
     */
    private void makeFragmentTransaction(int selection) {

        switch (selection) {
            case 0:
                mFragment = FragmentOne.newInstance(mSelected = 0);
                break;
            case 1:
                mFragment = FragmentTwo.newInstance(mSelected = 1);
                break;
        }

        // Create new transaction
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
        // and add the transaction to the back stack
        transaction.replace(R.id.frame, mFragment);

        /*This would add the Fragment to the backstack...
        * But right now we comment it out.*/
        //        transaction.addToBackStack(null);

        // Commit the transaction
        transaction.commit();
    }

}
```

**And sample Fragment:**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

/**
 * @author Martin Pfeffer (pepperonas)
 */
public class FragmentOne extends Fragment {

    private static final String TAG = "FragmentOne";


    public static Fragment newInstance(int i) {
        Fragment fragment = new FragmentOne();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("the_id", i);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView  " + "");
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
    }

}
```

Can be found on [github](https://github.com/pepperonas/AndroidTest).

Answer (score 4):

You may use the ViewModel object in your activity.

ViewModel objects are automatically retained during configuration changes so that the data they hold is immediately available to the next activity or fragment instance.
Read more:
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel

Answer (score 0):

You can lock to the current orientation of the screen using this code...

```
int currentOrientation =context.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
        if (currentOrientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
            ((Activity) context).setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        } else {
            ((Activity) context). setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

add this code to your manifest.xml.

this is your activity.

```
<activity
....
..
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

**in that activity set `config changes` like below**

```
 android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this:

- **Use Flag inside onCreate**

  **in your manifest file add the below line**

> ```
>  > android:screenOrientation="portrait"
> ```

**and in onCreate()**

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

- **Use onConfigurationChanged() method**

**in your manifest file add the below line / for Android 3.2 and later**

```
      

android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" / android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration config) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(config);

if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        //Handle rotation from landscape to portrait mode here
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){
        //Handle rotation from portrait to landscape mode here
    }
}
```

- **Use onSaveInstanceState()**

  @Override
  public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
  /*Save your data to be restored here
  Example: outState.putLong("time_state", time); , time is a long variable*/
  super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
  }

**and to restore**

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

```
if(savedInstanceState!= null){
   /*When rotation occurs
    Example : time = savedInstanceState.getLong("time_state", 0); */
} else {
  //When onCreate is called for the first time
}
```

}